# Trouble with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse for J2EE developement

what seems to be my problem?

the files at the address  (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java)  are:
**jdk1.6.0_02**,
**jre1.6.0,**
**jre1.6.0_02**,
**jre7**

[image: error]

Comment: If the file is in place, possible problem is mismatch between architectures (x86, x64), otherwise it is invalid JRE/JDK installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible if the eclipse is 64 bit and the JDK or JRE is 32 bit. Check this.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

tells that you are using **32 bit JRE and JDK**, but the JUNO that you have is of **64 bit**. So use 64 bit JRE/JDK and the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not joking about this: a friend of mine had this issue loading Netbeans 7, and we couldn't figure it out. Eventually for some reason he closed his desktop clock gadget (the one that comes with Windows 7) and suddenly it started working again. I can't explain how or why it worked, but don't rule it out (unless of course you aren't using gadgets).